# POST requests are sent twice with certain delay between them to Express route

Tags: node.js, http, express

I have an Express route `/chat/send` for sending messages which gets user's ID from session and message. It works okay, but I noticed that requests are sent again after some period of time, without any action (I was doing something in the background and checked console again). I tried to restart server and check again and problem persists.

This is route:

```
app.post('/chat/send', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    let id = req.user.id;
    let message = req.body.message;
    let currentTime = new Date().getTime();

    if (message.trim() !== "") {
        console.log('ID: ' + id + ' Message: ' + message + ' Time: ' + currentTime);
    }
});

// here is the method for ensuring that authentication is done

let ensureAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

This is client side code:

```
$("#send-message").on("click", function() {
    $.post('/chat/send', { message: $("#chat-message").val() });
    $("#chat-message").val("");
});

$("#chat-message").keypress( function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $.post('/chat/send', { message: $("#chat-message").val() });
        $("#chat-message").val("");
        return false;
    }
});
```

As I said, I was not in the same tab when this happened so I'm pretty sure I haven't clicked on button for sending message or pressed Enter.

Screenshot of terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSTs can be retried; because you're not replying to the request at all, no response is ever delivered to the browser, and it assumes the request failed. It *should* then retry the request, which is what appears to be happening here.

To fix, just reply with anything in your Express handler, even if you just call `res.end()`.

Ref: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.2.4